# How do I delete all unused imports in the active file with one command in VS Code (typescript)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Previously, I used to be able to do <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> > `Organize imports` and this would both sort and delete unused imports. This functionality seems to have broken.

How can I delete unused imports quickly with one command?

Current workaround is: click on unused import, <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> > `Delete unused imports`.

[image]

Languages for which this is applicable (typescript, typescriptreact, javascript, javascriptreact).

I have confirmed VS code is using a recent version of typescript unlike [people in this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60303) [image]

Comment: I believe it was introduced with typescript 4.6 on feb 28

Comment: Can you show VS Code's `settings.json`

Comment: I have "Organize imports" enabled on file saves, so whenever I save a file or have it automatically save (I have that also enabled) it automatically organizes imports.

Comment: I think you misunderstood @kellys

Comment: what is your vs code version? I'm still able to remove unused imports with organize imports on version 1.66.2, both the keybinding and command palette version

Comment: I'm also on  1.66.2 perhaps there is some other thing conflicting with this functionality   Good to know it still works for you @nullptr

Comment: You can additionally use ```eslint``` to automatically delete unused imports.

Comment: @david_adler Are you on macOS? I'm on mac, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Yes I am indeed

Comment: I used extension bisect and found it's one of my extensions which confirms @nullptr 's findings digging to find out which one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `Organize Imports` does actually work as expected but it was conflicting with the `Deno` plugin.

I found this out by using the amazingly useful [Extension Bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52#_troubleshooting-extension-bisect) feature which is built into Visual Studio Code. Extension Bisect disables half your extensions and asks you to check if the issue persists. This process is repeated until only a single extension is left. I strongly recommend trying it out via <kbd>CMD+SHIFT+P</kbd> > `Start Extension Bisect`

Turns out my issue is a [duplicate of this GitHub issue](https://github.com/denoland/vscode_deno/issues/650).

Comment: @Guillaume Esquevin let me know if that works for you! 

Comment: Thank you so much ! I indeed use the deno extension, and extra thanks for explaining how you figured it out 

Answer (score 2):

In v1.73 there should be a command (it is in Insiders already) to remove all unused imports, see [Merged PR: Add removeUnusedImports command](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/161654):

```
{
  "key": "",
  "command": "javascript.removeUnusedImports"
},

{
  "key": "",
  "command": "typescript.removeUnusedImports"
}
```

These are unbound by default and although they are in the Keyboard Shortcuts editor they don't appear in the Command Pallette for some reason.

---

Previous answer which may still help some:

There does not appear to be a built-in way to access the `delete all imports` functionality.  But you can install the [Remove Unused Imports](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kuscamara.remove-unused-imports) extension

> VS Code extension to remove unused ES6 imports inside JavaScript and
> TypeScript files (`.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts` and `.tsx` extensions) without
> changing the current order, as opposed to the built-in VS Code
> "Organize Imports" functionality.

and

try this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+shift+r",            // or whatever you want
  "command": "remove-unused-imports.main",
}
```

Comment: There used to be this functionality so it's strange that it's been removed but thanks!

Comment: This plugin has an issue for react that it removes `React` even though it's required to be in scope for jsx / tsx files

Comment: Odd there is no issue posted on that.  He does appear to be quick on fixing issues.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is now built in. First, you'll see that unused imports are greyed out. There's a lightbulb for code actions, and that includes a menu for deleting all unused imports.

[image]